# What does the double forward slash mean in this context?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I came across some code that looks like this:

```
get dropdownElement() {
  return $(`//button[@class='name_here']//span[contains(., 'Dropdown')]`);
}
```

And I'm confused as to what the "//" means here; I know that double backslashes are typically meant to escape a character, but I don't think I've ever seen a double forward slash. Also, when I see back ticks, they're usually accompanied by "$" so I was wondering about that too.

Comment: This looks like a XPath selector to me. See https://devhints.io/xpath for translations into CSS selectors.

Comment: If this is actually jQuery, it's likely a very old version, as XPath selectors were removed from base jQuery in [**2007**](https://blog.jquery.com/2007/09/10/jquery-1-2-released/) (and the [XPath plugin](https://github.com/ilinsky/jquery-xpath) uses a different method to call it). I'm curious, where is this code from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is using [XPath syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) to select elements with jQuery. The double slash essentially means "select all descendants that match this selector".

So `//button[@class='name_here']` matches all elements that are buttons with the `name_here` class, and `//button[@class='name_here']//span[contains(., 'Dropdown')]` matches elements that descendants from those buttons, and are spans, and contain `Dropdown`.